# How to update multiple instances of a class at once in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a game-like program and it has a class that has to act as an item. Normally I would just keep it as an item but every one has to wait 10 game-days in order to start doing what it's meant to. Is there a way to update the days in all the classes at once? I've tried to use a static method but you can't use instance variables in those so it didn't work. I've thought about possibly making a code that expands every time a new instance is made but I can't find anything i can understand about it. Is there any way to add to a method, make this an item, anything? This is what I have at the moment:

```
    public class Tree
    {
        private boolean fullGrown;
        private int day;
        private int APDay; //apples per day
        private static int totalApples;
        public Tree()
        {
            fullGrown = false;
            day = 0;
            APDay = (int) (Math.random()*2) + 4;
        }

        public void updateDay()
        {
            day = day + 1;
            if (day == 10) fullGrown = true;
            if (fullGrown == true) totalApples = totalApples + APDay;
        }

        public void skipGrowth()
        {
            fullGrown = true;
        }
    }
```

Although this works, you have to update the day for every instance separately. I need a way to update all the instances at the same time. This will also be used by a code and not the actual interface, just in case that's helpful.

Comment: Use a List and loop through the instances. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Perhaps you could implements the Observer pattern ?  Have your class "listen" to your model (ie: days). When the "days" are updated, the model (observable) notfies all view-item (observer) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: If I understand this correctly.  If this is game logic, unless all players gain the item at the same time, then using a single variable for all of them would be inappropriate.  Some people who joined late, for example day 6, would only have to wait 4 days for the first 10 day.

Answer (score 1):

Observer and factory pattern looks like a good candidate here.

I hope the code below explain rest to you

```
public interface DayEventListener {
      public void onDay10(DayEvent DayEvent);
```

}

```
public class DayEvent {

     //... pojo

 }

public class AwesomeGame {

       private List<DayEventListener> dayEventListenerList = new ArrayList<>();

       public void addDayListener(DayEventListener del) {
          dayEventListener.add(del);
       }

       public void fireDay10Event(DayEvent de) {
           for(DayEventListener del : dayEventListenerList) {
               del.onDay10(de);

       }
}


public class Item  implements DayEventListener {
    //All constructors should be private

    public static Item buildItem() {
        Item Item = new Item();
        awesomeGame.addDayEventListener(Item);
        return item;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think class Item should use addDayListener, unless you want to update Awesome games function.  In addition the list name dayEventListenerList is called as dayEventListener in the addDayListener function.  Good use of Patterns.

Comment: thank you i haven't learned enough to use an interface but i'll do some research and use this

Answer (score 0):

so I did some research and while I was working on another project I discovered that i could use a vector to keep track of all my instances, so here is that class:

```
import java.util.Vector;

    public class catcher
    {
        private static Vector allInstances = new Vector();
        private int catchLeft;
        private String name;

        public catcher(String name)
        {
            catchLeft = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(name.indexOf("#") + 1, name.length()));
            catchLeft--;
            this.name = name;
            if (catchLeft != 0) allInstances.add(this);
        }

        public static synchronized Vector getAllInstances()
        {
            return (Vector) (allInstances.clone());
        }

        public boolean check(String name, boolean change)
        {
            boolean foo;
            if (this.name.equals(name)) 
            {
                if (change == true) catchLeft--;
                foo = true;
            }
            else foo = false;
            if (catchLeft <= 0) this.finalize();
            return foo;
        }

        public void finalize()
        {
            allInstances.removeElement(this);
        }

        public static void clear()
        {
            allInstances.clear();
        }
    }
```

now that I have a record of all the instances, I used this method in another class to assess all the instances:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

public class recipe
{
    private boolean checkForList(String name, boolean add)
    {
        Iterator list = catcher.getAllInstances().iterator();
        boolean running = true;
        boolean booleanReturn = true;
        while (running == true)
        {
            if (list.hasNext())
            {
                catcher Foo = (catcher) (list.next());
                if (Foo.check(name, false) == true) 
                {
                    Foo.check(name, true);
                    running = false;
                    booleanReturn = true;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (add == true) new catcher(name);
                running = false;
                booleanReturn = false;
            }
        }
        return booleanReturn;
    }
}
```

I'm sure that this can be modified to update the classes instead of just accessing them.